# Bullets and numbering Icon do not appear in Tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

According to tinymce [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#toolbarcontrols), code for bullets and numbering is "bullist" and "numlist". But adding them did not worked on mine.
My code is something like:

```
    toolbar: [
        'undo redo | bold italic | indent outdent bullist numlist'
    ]
```

Everything I added works except "bullist" and "numlist".
I am using tinymce 4.5.0(2016-11-23).
So what may be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use those toolbar options you need to load the `lists` plugin in your TinyMCE init.  You can also optionally add the `advlist` plugin for additional functionality.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/lists/
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/advlist/